# Get dynamic property from Settings

Tags: c#, .net, settings, app-config

I've got a few properties stored in my AppConfig and now I want to access them dynamically (e.g. in a loop or function).

Accessing the values using MySettings.NAME_OF_THAT_THING is no problem, but what if the name is variable?

I tried:

```
String propertyValue = MySettings.GetType().GetProperty("NAME_OF_THAT_THING").ToString();
```

But the only thing I got back is the name of the property. How can I do this?

Comment: What is the type of MySettings? Does it not implement iDictionary or something? I'd have expected you to be able to do `MySettings("NAME_OF_THING")`...

Comment: Application.Properties.Settings

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
String propertyValue = MySettings.GetType()
.GetProperty("NAME_OF_THAT_THING")
.GetValue(MySettings, null); //replace MySettings with null in GetValue(...) if MySettings is  a static class
```

Answer (score 11):

All you need to do is:

```
String propertyValue = Settings.Default["NAME_OF_THAT_THING"].ToString();
```

While using reflection will obviously work, it's overkill.

Comment: I have no "MySettings.Default": (no method Default in this context)

Comment: Interesting.  Is it a WinForm application?  Maybe it only adds that property if it's a WinForm application...

Comment: @user1450661 Try it now.  I mixed up Settings and MySettings.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [ConfigurationManager.AppSettings property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?  You should be able to get your setting via the following code:

```
String propertyValue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NAME_OF_THAT_THING"];
```

The MSDN article for ConfigurationManager.AppSettings also includes an example for looping through all of the entries in AppSettings by index, rather than name.

Comment: The settings the OP is referring to are not stored in the appSettings element of the config file, they are stored using a more complex structure under the applicationSettings element.

Answer (score 0):

answer to the orginal poster question would be like:
MySettings[NAME_OF_THAT_THINGmysettings] does the job like previous post

however for those people looking for answer to using the builtin settings in their windows app:
myAppDefaultNameSpace.Properties.Settings.Default[NAME_OF_THAT_THINGmysettings]
is the way to go